# Python Problems Concerning Out of Range Indices

Tags: python

I am always plagued with problems that involve checking values for indices i and i+1 within a for loop. However, doing so causes IndexError. One solution is to use range-1 but often that fails to check the last index value.

For example, given the following problem:

> Write a function that compares two DNA sequences based on the
>   following scoring scheme: +1 for a match, +3 for each consecutive
>   match and -1 for each mismatch.

I wrote the solution in the following way:

```
def pairwiseScore(seqA, seqB):
    if len(seqA) != len(seqB):
        return 'Length mismatch'

    count = 0
    for i in range(len(seqA)-1):
        if seqA[i] == seqB[i] and seqA[i+1] == seqB[i+1]:
            count += 3
        elif seqA[i] == seqB[i]:
            count += 1
        else:
            count -= 1
            #print count
    return "Score: {c:d}".format(c=count)


print pairwiseScore("ATTCGT", "ATCTAT")
```

When I run this, I get a score of 1. This is because the program's missing the last index. I can see this if I print the values:

```
A A
T T
T C
C T
G A
Score: 1
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

It should return a score of 2.

Another string to check:

```
pairwiseScore("GATAAATCTGGTCT", "CATTCATCATGCAA")
```

This should return a score of 4

How do I resolve such types of problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like that

```
def pairwiseScore(seqA, seqB):
   a=len(seqA)
   if a != len(seqB):
       return 'Length mismatch'

   count = 0
   for i in range(0,a):
       if seqA[i] == seqB[i] and i+1<a and seqA[i+1] == seqB[i+1]:
           count += 3
       elif seqA[i] == seqB[i]:
           count += 1
       else:
           count -= 1
   return "Score: {c:d}".format(c=count)


print pairwiseScore("GATAAATCTGGTCT", "CATTCATCATGCAA")
```

#### Explanation:

---

Assuming the lengths are equal. The first element in a list starts with zero. That's why I'm using `range(0,a)`. Then, if `i+1<a` equals to `True`, that means *there is an element after `seqA[i]`*, so one can use `seqB[i+1]` as the lengths are equal.

Moreover, `range(0,a)` 'counts' from zero to `a-1`, where `a=len( seqA )`. In Python 2.7.x `range` returns a list that certainly consumes memory. If `len(seqA)` might be a very big number, I'd suggest to use `xrange` instead. In Python 3.x you don't need such a precaution.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Is this the most efficient way of doing it? Of course, such a question may warrant a new post. :-)

Comment: @Rohit, your case is one of the simplest ones as the lengths are equal. You could optimize this a very little bit by putting the value of `i+1` into another variable and then comparing with it, but that should be overkill. All in all, the algorithm often depends on the situation. Everything you should do is to calculate whether you're using valid indices and to check whether these indices are _not_ greater than the size of your list.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you're only checking the first len(seq)-1 digits. If you want to check all of the digits, you need to for loop through the entire range(len(seq)). To avoid getting an IndexError, place a check at the beginning of the for loop to determine whether you're at the last position. If you are, don't make the consecutive sequence check.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. ForceBru code really helped me visualize.